# python for loop cycling through list of variables

Tags: python, list, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I have many turtles in my current python script.  They are named t1, t2, t3, t4...  I have a lot of setup to do for each turtle, so rather than type

```
t1.speed(0)
t2.speed(0)
t3.speed(0)
t4.speed(0)

t1.hideturtle()
t2.hideturtle()
t3.hideturtle()
t4.hideturtle()
```

It seems like I should be able to put them into a list,

```
x = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]
```

and then have a for loop do something like this

```
for i in range(0,3):
    x.speed(0)
    x.hideturtle()
```

So it would loop through 4 times, moving on to the next variable in x each pass through.  That is what I want it to do at least.  I am not the best at for loops, and I have looked at all related threads and guides, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Also, should I use

```
length = len(x)
for i in range(length):
    #stuff
```

So that all I have to do is add a new turtle to the list, rather than having to change the amount of loop passes in each for loop?  I hope that makes sense, please comment if it doesn't and I'll edit to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 3):

Put your variables in the list, instead of string literals:

```
x = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
```

Then you can do:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  #stuff, like:
  x[i].hideturtle()
```

or simply:

```
for turtle in x:
    turtle.hideturtle()
    # etc.
```

You may also want to take a look at using a `class`.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

```
class turtle():
    """ example of a class representing some sort of turtle """
    def __init__(self):
        # assign the default properties of the class
        self.speed = 0
        self.hidden = False
    def hideturtle(self):
        self.hidden = True
    def unhideturtle(self):
        self.hidden = False
    def setspeed(self, increment):
        # increase/decrease the current speed
        self.speed = 0 if self.speed += increment < 0 else self.speed += increment
    def stop(self):
        self.speed = 0


x = turtle()
y = turtle()

x.speed, y.speed = 10, 5
x.hideturtle()
print x.speed, y.speed, x.hidden, y.hidden

>>> 10, 5, True, False
```

To create 5 turtles in a list, all instantiated to whatever your base "setup" is:

```
turtles = []
for i in range(5):
  turtles.append(turtle())
```

And of course it should go without saying, once you have defined your class `turtle` object, you can now write code that can dynamically add turtles based on whatever conditions you might require.

Comment: for turle in x is more pythonic than using the range.

Comment: Yes @gipsy  amended to include that, I was working originally from OP's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for is something like this:

```
x = [t1, t2, t3, t4]

for t in x:
    t.speed(0)
    t.hideturtle()
```

`x` is a list of all your turtles. When you do `for t in x` it will loop through your list and assign `t` as the current turtle, then set its speed and hide it. This way there is no need to use `range(len(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
x = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
for item in x:
    item.speed(0)
    item.hideturtle()
```

or

```
x = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    x[i].speed(0)   # you should change the element in x, rather use x
    x[i].hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding string representation of your turtles into the list add turtle objects itself.

For example

```
turtles = [t1, t2, t3, t4] # t1, t2, t3, and t4 are turtle objects
```

Then iterate over turtles and call your methods:

```
for turtle in turtles:
  turtle.speed(0)
  turtle.hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
turtles = [t1, t2, t3, t4]

# explicitly
for t in turtles:
    t.speed(0)

# wrapped up a bit more
def turtle_do(fn):
    for t in turtles:
        fn(t)
turtle_do(lambda t: t.hideturtle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Or to be much concise and explore the world of lambdas

```
turtles = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
map(lambda x: x.speed(0), turtles)
map(lambda x: x.hideTurtle(), turtles)
```

Comment: Short but maps with side effects are ugly IMO

Comment: I haven't come across any. Could you make me aware of it? user2398029.

Comment: Map comes from functional programming. Map is an operation that takes a function mapping a domain D to a range R. Here you are using it to modify the variables passed to map (instances of turtles), which is not really idiomatic.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the knowledge transfer :) user2398029